# Parameters.AddWithValue: Parameter has already been defined

Tags: vb.net, parameters, combobox

I try to add a parameters.addwithvalue.
Before change the code is like that..........

```
    Private Sub ComboBox7_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox7.SelectedIndexChanged


    Me.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor
    MysqlConn.Close()
    MysqlConn.Open()
    COMMAND.CommandText = "select logo from licenses where name = '" & ComboBox7.Text & "'"
    COMMAND.Connection = MysqlConn

    Dim da As New MySqlDataAdapter(COMMAND)
    Dim ds As New DataSet()
    da.Fill(ds, "projectimages")
    Dim c As Integer = ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count
    If c > 0 Then
        If IsDBNull(ds.Tables(0).Rows(c - 1)("logo")) = True Then
            PictureBox6.Image = Nothing
        Else
            Dim bytBLOBData() As Byte = ds.Tables(0).Rows(c - 1)("logo")
            Dim stmBLOBData As New MemoryStream(bytBLOBData)
            PictureBox6.Image = Image.FromStream(stmBLOBData)
        End If
    End If
    Me.Cursor = Cursors.Default
End Sub
```

Now what i try this to add paramatrers.addwithValue without succes:

```
    Private Sub ComboBox7_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox7.SelectedIndexChanged


    Me.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor
    MysqlConn.Close()
    MysqlConn.Open()
    'COMMAND.CommandText = "select logo from licenses where name = '" & ComboBox7.Text & "'"
    COMMAND.CommandText = "select logo from licenses where name = @ComboBox7Select"
    COMMAND.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ComboBox7Select", If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(ComboBox7.Text), DBNull.Value, ComboBox7.Text))
    COMMAND.Connection = MysqlConn

    Dim da As New MySqlDataAdapter(COMMAND)
    Dim ds As New DataSet()
    da.Fill(ds, "projectimages")
    Dim c As Integer = ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count
    If c > 0 Then
        If IsDBNull(ds.Tables(0).Rows(c - 1)("logo")) = True Then
            PictureBox6.Image = Nothing
        Else
            Dim bytBLOBData() As Byte = ds.Tables(0).Rows(c - 1)("logo")
            Dim stmBLOBData As New MemoryStream(bytBLOBData)
            PictureBox6.Image = Image.FromStream(stmBLOBData)
        End If
    End If
    Me.Cursor = Cursors.Default
End Sub
```

With error "Parameter '@ComboBox7Select' has already been defined."

What i do to change for work ??

Thanks you.

Comment: Don't store the MySqlConnection and MySqlCommand as fields in your class, don't reuse them at all. That's just a source of errors without any benefit. Create, initialize, use and dispose(`Using`-statement) wherever you need them.

Comment: as long your form is open and you change the index one you will have created the value So either use a command just inside that sub or intialize the parameters with `.Add` on form load then just change the `.Value` on index change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using a global variable `COMMAND` that you use each time the selected index changes in your combo. Either you initialize the command each time with:

```
COMMAND=New MySqlCommand()
```

Or you must clear the parameters:

```
COMMAND.Parameters.Clear()
COMMAND.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ComboBox7Select", If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(ComboBox7.Text), DBNull.Value, ComboBox7.Text))
```

But the best way is always create and dispose the `MySql` objects with the `Using` struct:

```
Using MysqlConn As New MySqlConnection(connString)
    Using COMMAND As New MySqlCommand()
    'your code 
    End Using
End Using
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't store the `MySqlConnection` and `MySqlCommand` as fields in your class, don't reuse them at all. That's just a source of errors without any benefit. Create, initialize, use and dispose(`Using`-statement)them wherever you need them, so in this method.

You don't clear the parameters, that's why you get this error on second use.

So a simple `COMMAND.Parameters.Clear()` before you add it would solve the issue. But use the approach i have mentioned above:

```
Private Sub ComboBox7_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox7.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim ds As New DataSet()
    Dim licenseNameValue As Object = DBNull.Value
    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(ComboBox7.Text) Then licenseNameValue = ComboBox7.Text

    Using mysqlConn As New MySqlConnection("ConnectionString...")
        Using da As New MySqlDataAdapter("select logo from licenses where name = @licenseName", mysqlConn)
            da.SelectCommand.CommandText = "select logo from licenses where name = @licenseName"
            da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@licenseName", licenseNameValue)
            da.Fill(ds, "projectimages") ' you dont need to open/close the connection with DataAdapter.Fill
        End Using
    End Using

    ' ....
End Sub
```